# Call a method from a build event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, post-build-event, build-events

is it possible to make a method call from a postbuild event?

```
namespace Test
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            // Do something
        }
     }
}
```

Of course this class resides in a project whose build events I specify. Is there a way to call DoSomething as a postbuild event?

Comment: Not really, no; unless you package one of your projects as an exe, or use powershell to load and invoke from an assembly...

Comment: @MarcGravell: Powershell is the other idea I thought of - just no idea how to use it properly :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this directly, but you could include a small executable as part of your solution, with a reference to the method you want to call.

Once the solution builds, trigger it to fire the executable you just compiled and you should be there.