# call function when "build solution" is called on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-optimization

Im using Visual Studio 2015,
with .NET Framework 4.6

I want to call a function that will make lots of core actions
when ever I call "Build Solution" or "Rebuild Solution"
is this possible?

Comment: You can't really call a function this way. But you can use Build Events for this to make a workaround. Take a look on this [How to: Specify Build Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) . Also there is a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454473/call-a-method-from-a-build-event) on stackoverflow.

Comment: thank you! works great... just a minor issue, maybe i can use your help.. i am now running a console application file when ever I build the solution.. but a command line is poping up when ever its called. can I prevent command line to popup?

Comment: For this you can change the output for the project. Project properties -> Application tab -> and can change Output Type ( you will probably want Class Library)

Comment: perfect. thank you so much!